# Incorrect values in atlas.urdf

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Perhaps I don't understand the arguments for **safety_controller** correctly, but shouldn't the **soft_lower_limit** and **soft_upper_limit** values be within the joint limits specified in **limit**? Also, these values are in radians, so a value such as 10.6109 doesn't make much sense given knowledge of the robot's capabilities. Are these values a typo or am I misunderstanding their meaning?

```
<joint name="back_lbz" type="revolute">
  ...
  <limit effort="124.016" velocity="12" lower="-0.610865" upper="0.610865" />
  <safety_controller k_position="100" k_velocity="100" soft_lower_limit="-10.6109" soft_upper_limit="10.6109" />
</joint>
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2162/incorrect-values-in-atlas.urdf/) by [david_rusbarsky](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/147/david_rusbarsky/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-04-01

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-04-02**:
Would like to see this addressed, so I created https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/172/safety-limits-out-of-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `<safety_controller>` is no longer in use since the pr2_controllers are no longer used. The corresponding drcsim ticket has been marked won't fix.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0